# Subspace $V$ of $\rm{M}_n(\mathbb{C})$ such that $\exists M_1,M_2\in V$ that $C(M_1)\cap C(M_2)=\mathbb{C}I_n$

Tags: linear-algebra

> Problem: Find all subspace $V$ of $\rm{M}_n(\mathbb{C})$ such that
> $\exists M_1,M_2\in V$ that $C(M_1)\cap C(M_2)=\mathbb{C}I_n$. (where
> $C(M)$ contains all matrices that commute with $M$)

For example,let $A=\rm{diag}(1,2,3,...,n)$, $B$ be the matrix with  1 on entries $(j,j+1)$ and 0 elsewhere, then $V=\mathbb{C}A+\mathbb{C}B$ is one of such subspace.

I don't even know how to start. I only found some facts related to this problem:

1, For $X\in C(M)$: Let $m_{ij}$ be $(i,j)$ entry of $M$, $x_{ij}$ be $(i,j)$ entry of $X$, then
$$\begin{pmatrix}
m_{11}I_n-M^T & m_{12}I_n & m_{13}I_n &... & m_{1n}I_n\\
m_{21}I_n & m_{22}I_n-M^T & m_{23}I_n &... & m_{2n}I_n\\
m_{31}I_n & m_{32}I_n & m_{33}I_n-M^T &... & m_{3n}I_n\\
... & ... & ...& ... & ...\\\
m_{n1}I_n & m_{n2}I_n & m_{n3}I_n &... & m_{nn}I_n-M^T
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
x_{11}\\
x_{12}\\
... \\
x_{21} \\
x_{22}\\
...\\
x_{nn}
\end{pmatrix}=0$$
For example, we can use it to show that $C(\rm{diag}(1,2,3,...,n))=\mathbb{C}I_n$

2, $C(M)$ is a ring; if it is considered as a vector space, its dimension is  $\geq n$.

3, The centre of $M_n(\mathbb{C})$ is $\mathbb{C}I_n$.

My main focus was on the properties of commuting matrices, but I didn't really see any connection between facts. I was trying to start with some lower dimension cases, but no clear pattern was found yet.
But I am (mostly) sure that there is a clear answer because it was found on a problem sheet from school 3 months ago.

Comment: Why not just ask for the pairs of matrices such that (etc.)? (But may be your choice will seem more natural when we know the answer.)

Comment: @AnneBauval I don't know, they are equivalent, probably because there is no nice form of answer if asking "pairs of matrices".